# Promise return pending not the value inside a function using async/await

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a code to read files' paths from a directory, and return them.
i use async/await to call the function to do this, but i got Promise pending not the target value.

```
function readdirAsync(path) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(path, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  }).then(res => {
    const versions = res.map(filename => match(/^[\d]+(\.+\d+)+/g, filename)[0]);
    return versions;
  });
}

async function getVersions() {
  const final = await readdirAsync(require('path').join('src/versions/'));
  return final;
}



const versionsList = getVersions().then(res => res);
console.log(versionsList);
```

Comment: getVersions().then(res => console.log(res)); try this.

Comment: It works fine, but i need to set `versionsList` to `res`

Comment: @ZeyadEtman I have rolled back your last edit, because you should not change an existing question in such a way that it invalidates answers that have already been given. If you believe your question is not a duplicate, you can edit your question to explain how your question differs. If you have additional follow-up questions based on this question and answers given, you can ask a new question and link this question in it. You may be able to find an answer to some or all of those questions by searching around on stackoverflow, or by examining the related questions when asking one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` only waits for a promise to resolve *inside an asyncronous function*.

`getVersions` is an `async` function, so it returns a promise (which, when it resolves, resolves with the value `final`).

> ```
> const versionsList = getVersions().then(res => res);
> ```

You aren't `await`ing here (and can't, because you aren't in an async function), so you get the return value of the `then()` method … which is the promise.

Comment: Ok, but if i need to set `versionsList` to `res` value, what should i do?

Comment: @ZeyadEtman — "because you aren't in an async function" <-- Change that fact.

Comment: Please, could you check the code after editing?

Comment: @ZeyadEtman — `const final = readdirAsync` still isn't `await`ing and still is not inside an `async` function (so it still can't `await`).

Comment: sorry, Could you help me further?